# objc_msgSend call NSScreen backingScaleFactor return NSScreenAux?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem that objc_msgSend call NSScreen backingScaleFactor function, but objc_msgSend return NSScreenAux type by NSLog, NSScreen backingScaleFactor should return CGFloat type in document, anyone have the problem?

```
NSScreen *screen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"%@", objc_msgSend(screen, @selector(userSpaceScaleFactor))
```

NSLog print "NSScreenAux: 0x1661210"

I have a new problem. objc_msgSend call the function

```
- (NSRect)convertRectToBacking:(NSRect)aRect NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7);
```

the code is following :

```
NSScreen* screen = [NSScreen mainScreen]; 
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100); 
NSLog(@" %@ ", objc_msgSend(screen, @selector(convertRectToBacking:), rect));
```

the app crash, i don't know what to do?

Comment: It would help if we could see some code

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems.

1. You are not ready to use `objc_msgSend`.  The fact that you are using the wrong format specifier in your format string is a red flag.
2. Your question text says `backingScaleFactor` but your code says `userSpaceScaleFactor`.  Which one do you want?
3. Both `userSpaceScaleFactor` and `backingScaleFactor` are documented to return `CGFloat`.  On OS X, `CGFloat` is a `typedef` for `float` under 32-bit and `double` under 64-bit, so you must use `%f` to format a `CGFloat`, not `%@`.
4. When you want to send a message that returns a `float`, `double`, or `long double` , you must use `objc_msgSend_fpret` if compiling for 32-bit, but `objc_msgSend` if compiling for 64-bit.
5. You must always cast `objc_msgSend` (or `objc_msgSend_fpret`) to the type of the method you're calling.

So, to make this work on 32-bit:

```
NSScreen *screen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"%f", ((CGFloat (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend_fpret)(screen, @selector(backingScaleFactor)));
```

To make it work on 64-bit:

```
NSScreen *screen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"%f", ((CGFloat (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(screen, @selector(backingScaleFactor)));
```

Comment: because of the froum's limit for the new, yestoday i can't reply you. 1 In face, i use the function objc_msgSend several times. 2 userSpaceScaleFactor is deprecated in OS X v10.7, backingScaleFactor is available in OS X v10.7 and later. i need get scale factor by the both function. 3 the function objc_msgSend return id type, i think NSLog need the "%@" format to print. 4, 5 i need to seed the documents again. thanks for you again!!!

Comment: I have a new problem. objc_msgSend call the function `- (NSRect)convertRectToBacking:(NSRect)aRect NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7);` the code is following :`NSScreen* screen = [NSScreen mainScreen]; NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100); NSLog(@" %@ ", objc_msgSend(screen, @selector(convertRectToBacking:), rect));` the app crash, i don't know what to do?

Comment: Don't try to paste code in a comment.  It's too hard to read.  Edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: Just do `[screen contentRectToBacking:rect]`, or explain why you don't want to do that.